# Display SSRS report with ASP.NET MVC 3 application on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, azure

I've been searching for almost 2 days, but I still don't manage to do what I want.

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 application on Windows Azure, and I would like to give to users report made with SQL Server Reporting Services.

I've created a test report, published it on my Sql Azure server, and I'm able to access it with the URL. (Even tough I have to connect with my Username/Password, and I don't like that).

I want my users to click on a link/button on my application, and without any actions of them, a PDF or HTML version of my report open and they can print it.

I've had a WebReference of my Sql Azure report server, but I don't know what to do to athenticate programmatically and how to have my reports.

Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: "Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope." :D That's the best closing comment I've seen on SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer !

I've found this [sample my Microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-reporting-samples.aspx) with working code exemple to work with Sql Azure. Hope it can help somebody one day.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, I think, is to use the Report Viewer to render your report on a page. Since it's a web control, you might need to combine the ASP.NET Web Form and MVC together, which means only this page is Web Form while others are MVC.

Then you can pass your authentication information into the Report Viewer, and specify the remote report path and name, and the parameters needed to run your report. The Report Viewer itself has the feature to download the report in many formats, such as PDF, Word, etc.

Use the SSRS web service is another way, when you want to get the report content programmatically. It's a standard web service, so you can pass your authentication same way you did to any other web services. I think it should be something like Credential and use.

Credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

Hope this helps.